# Why does this button selection in css work?

Tags: css, button

I have just started to learn how to code and I was trying to select the button class to change the color when you hover over it. I managed to make it work by selecting this in css:

```
.button[type="submit"]:hover  {
    
background-color: grey;
    

}
```

But I am wondering why this doesn't work instead:

```
 .button:hover {
    
background-color: grey;
    
}
```

here is my html code:

```
<form class="my-form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name= "name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Email: </label>
        <input type="text" name= "email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Message: </label>
        <textarea name= "message"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="submit" name="">

</form>
```

Comment: It should work just fine, are you sure you didn't reference the css file incorrectly or make other typos?

Comment: it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yr12b9s4/

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly, You probably faced not closed div's mistake's or something like this...
take a screenshot if you're sure that everything is alright with your code's.
this helps you to find mistaked like i said:
http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/end-tag-for-element-x-which-is-not-open/end-tag-for-element-div-which-is-not-open/

```css
 .button:hover {
    
background-color: grey;
    
}
```

```html
<form class="my-form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name= "name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Email: </label>
        <input type="text" name= "email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Message: </label>
        <textarea name= "message"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="submit" name="">

</form>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. It still doesn't work I must be making a mistake elsewhere. I will have to look at it with fresh eyes or something another time.

Comment: @Zaibaa
If you're okay share all of your codes in Codepen or  JSfiddle, Then i can help you again.